# Executing a function after Map() completes multiple Fecth API requests in React.js

Tags: reactjs, promise, fetch-api

Wrestling with promises here...

My users make a single request that requires multiple REST calls on the backend. I store each request made by the user and the two REST responses as an item in a 'records' array like so:

```
[
  {
    call:userRequest,
    responses: [
        {
          source:source1
          response:responseText
        },
        {
          source:source2
          response:responseText
        }
      ]
  }
]
```

I use a map function to make the mulitple REST API calls. I process each response using a 'setThisCall' method which adds details of each response to an array 'thisCall'. Once done, 'thisCall' is used as The value for 'responses' in the 'records' array is assigned to 'thisCall'.

```
await Promise.all(urls.map(async url =>  {
  
  fetch(url, { 
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: messageBody
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    setThisCall(prev => ([ //sets thisCall
      ...prev,
      {
        source: source,
        response: data.body
      }
    ]))
  })
})).then(()=>{
  console.log("now adding to records")
  setRecords(prev => ([ //sets records
    {
      call: requestText,
      reponses: thisCall
      },
      ...prev
    ]))
  })
```

I tried using Promise.all() to let the map function complete the fecthes and processing the responses and using 'then' to add the calls to ne next 'record' item.

But the final 'then' is firing before 'thisCall' is built resulting in an empty 'response' value in 'records'.

tl;dr - how do I make 'setRecords' happen AFTER the rest of the code has completed?

Comment: use `async`-`await` that will make your code clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

Setter function of useState hook is async in nature.
When `setRecords` is called, `thisCall` might not have been updated yet, that is why you’re seeing an empty `response` value in `records`.

## Solution

```
// Use async function to handle fetch request
async function fetchData(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: messageBody
  });
  const data = await response.json();
  // Update thisCall with the response data
  setThisCall(prev => ([ 
    ...prev,
    {
      source: source,
      response: data.body
    }
  ]));
}

// Use Promise.all to ensure all fetch requests are completed before setRecords
await Promise.all(urls.map(fetchData)).then(() => {
  // Update records after all fetch requests have completed
  setRecords(prev => ([ 
    {
      call: requestText,
      responses: thisCall
    },
    ...prev
  ]))
});
```